# NullPointerException when using findViewById

Tags: android

I am using the findViewById method in a fragment like this:

```
output = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.output);
```

Note that "output" is declared in XML.

This code runs with no errors on the screen but when I run my app, it gives me a NullPointerException:

```
03-09 12:50:33.507  28500-28500/com.andrewq.ezcalc E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hidden.hidden, PID: 28500
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.hidden.hidden.hidden.onCreateView(Hidden.java:50)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Also note that package names are hidden. I don't understand why this is happening because I've used the similar line of code several times in other apps that I code and this has never happened.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

As said in previous ans by blackbelt getView() returns the view you inflate inside onCreateView and its returning null because may be you are not inflating view before actually using

```
output = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.output);
```

try replacing your code with these lines

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mlayout,null);
output = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.output);
```

this is how it solved my prob. may be it would be helpful for you too..

Answer (score 1):

`getView()` returns the view you inflate inside `onCreateView` that's why it is returning null inside `onCreateView`. You can use the View returned by the inflater or move all the `findViewById` related logic inside [onViewCreated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated%28android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle%29)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to blackbelt's help, I got it working. Here's what I did:

I had the onCreateView declared like so:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle
   savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, container, false);
   ...
   output = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.output);
   ...
}
```

I got rid of getView(). and replaced it with this:

```
output = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.output);
```

Works great!